# Is there an interface for unmarshalling a TLS certificate in ASN.1 format

Tags: ssl, go, asn.1

I'm parsing TLS records, taken from a PCAP file.

I have the bytes of a TLS certificate in ASN.1 format (in a `[]byte`).

I want to unmarshall this byte slice into a useful structure (avoiding having to manually parse ASN.1).

I can't seem to find an interface for a TLS certificate that follows the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1) in either [encoding/asn1](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/asn1/#pkg-overview) nor [crypto/tls](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/).

Has this been created somewhere I can't find or do I need to write my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The struct is in the [x509 package](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#Certificate)